# React firebase delete operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Creating a simple application to learn firebase, wanting to delete a particular item in a list. So, decided to use this approach

```
  const handleDeletion = (name) => {
        db.collection('users').doc(`"${name}"`).delete().then(() => {
            console.log("document deleted successfully");
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("error:",err)
        })
    }
//don't mind syntax,below is my idea to delete the item
 <div>
            {docs && docs.map(doc => (
                <div key={doc.id}>
                    <h4>{doc.name}:{doc.password}</h4>                
                    <button onClick={() => handleDeletion(doc.name)}>Delete</button>
                </div>
            ))}
            
        </div>
```

I took this info from firebase web docs, but when runnning this does not delete the respective h4 and also the document but console says document deleted successfully.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't delete the DIV or it doesn't delete the doc in Firestore or both?

Comment: I edited the question as it says both is failing to occur.

Comment: @Muditx Note that if the document does not exist you will still get the "document deleted successfully" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most probably comes from the fact that you do `` db.collection('users').doc(`"${name}"`) ``. You should not use double quotes when declaring your [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): `` db.collection('users').doc(`${name}`) ``.

You can see the problem by doing:

```
const name = "abcd";
console.log(`"${name}"`) // => "abcd" instead of abcd
```

Comment: I figured out that i need to use id attribute, also yes i don't need quotes. But firebase docs should be improved.